# How to append to the last element of a 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

What i'm trying to do is create a 2 dimensional list. The outer list would be the student data, and the inner list is the student's name, which contains all their test scores.
If their name (the studentName) is already in the outer list, then it just appends another finalScore to the appropriate inner list.
However, I keep getting the error that I can't append to a string in the last line.

```
with open('class_three.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            studentName, finalScore = line.split(": ")
            finalScore = finalScore.rstrip("\n")
            studentDataList = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(30)] 
            if studentName in studentDataList:
                positionOfName = studentDataList.index(studentName)
                studentDataList[positionOfName].append(finalScore)
            else:
                studentDataList.append(studentName)
                studentDataList[-1].append(finalScore)
```

the file class_three.txt looks like so:

```
jak: 1
kate: 9
niki: 10
abi: 5
mart: 2
zeddy: 7
jak: 5
jak: 3
kate: 5
```

What can I do to fix the error I'm getting? Is there any way I can improve the method of what I'm trying to do? Any advice would be hugely appreciated. I also apologise if this is somewhat of a duplicate question.

Comment: `studentDataList.append(studentName)` adds a string to the end of `studentDataList`, so of course `studentDataList[-1].append(finalScore)` fails; did you want something like `studentDataList.append([studentName, finalScore])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a dictionary of lists for this:

```
studentDataDict = {}
with open('class_three.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        studentName, finalScore = line.strip().split(": ")
        if studentName in studentDataDict:
            studentDataDict[studentName].append(finalScore)
        else:
            studentDataDict[studentName] = [finalScore]
```

Then studentDataDict will look like:

```
{
    'abi': ['5'], 
    'niki': ['10'], 
    'kate': ['9', '5'], 
    'mart': ['2'], 
    'jak': ['1', '5', '3'], 
    'zeddy': ['7']
}
```

Comment: I had tried using dictionaries before but couldn't get it to append correctly. Thank you so much!!